# Referencing a column from another table on an entity in Kotlin Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I thought I could setup a unidirectional relationship with the following:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
class Transaction (
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "non_standard_id") 
    /**
     * `non_standard_id` exists in Account table, 
     * whereas `account_id` exists in transactions table
     */
    var account: Account,
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: Integer?,
)

data class Account(
    private val nonStandardId: String,
    private val name: String,
)
```

But I'm getting an error

> 'Many to One' attribute type should not be 'Account'

Should I be updating my database (Postgres), or in code, to help resolve?

Comment: Please, provide the `Account` class code as well. Besides, I think you should set `@JoinColumn(name = ...)` but not `@JoinColumn(columnDefinition = ...)` attribute

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It looks like I was missing some JPA annotations on the `Account` class.